# How to exchange TList items during a for-loop

Tags: delphi, list-manipulation

I have a `TList` which' items are continuously processed by many `for`-loops. I sometimes need to exchange items in the list in order to rearrange the order of the visual representation of the list (in a `StringGrid`).

How do I exchange these items?

My preliminary thoughts are:

- During the for-loop I think the items should not be exchanged.
- If I do the exchange in a Timers' `OnTimer` event, having set the Timers' interval to a very short interval (e.g. 1 millisecond), then I think the for-loop will have only an intermission of that one millisecond.

Will this work? Or are there better alternatives?

Comment: We are not going to be able to understand your question as stated. Please expand. Most likely include a more detailed description of your problem, and cut-down code.

Comment: When you say `I sometimes need to exchange items` it would be nice if you could explain better of why are you even doing this. What do you gain by this? Is it the need to change the order of these items because processing of one item might depend on another item already being processed before? Is it necessary for all item to be processed in every for lop or can some of them be skipped which could occur if you are moving some items so that their new location is before current loop point (item will never be processed because it is treaded as already being processed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you ensure that the count of the items in a `TList` does not change, exchanging items is perfectly fine during a for-loop. Note that, depending on the index of the items that are about to be exchanged, some of the items may not be processed or may be processed twice.

If the exchange operation is not called from within the for-loop, then an already started for-loop will run until it is done. You cannot expect to "break in" with a Timer, because that Timer's message will not be processed until the for-loop and all surrounding code is done.

So, the solution for your problem could be:

- exchange the items within the for-loop,
- use a threading solution to be able to do two different things simultaniously on one list (this may need some learning about threads),
- wait until the for-loop is done, and exchange then,
- split the for-loop in multiple slices to reduce the time needed, or
- use a timer to start multiple for-loops in order to give your program some breathing time in between.

Comment: @JO No place for timers here. You'd do better if you could explain the problem properly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan my problem was what ngln explained exactly.  i used a timer and it works well without outstanding overload. thanks.

Comment: You almost certainly have the wrong solution. But you don't want my advice. Which is fine.